# Cropping text on matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am making a plot and I *want* the text to crop at the edge. Right now it hangs over the edge, which is great for readability, but not what I actually want.

Here's a toy version of what I'm doing:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.scatter(np.random.random(10), np.random.random(10))
ax.text(0.8, 0.5, "a rather long string")

plt.show()
```

[image: my matplotlib example]

Just to be clear, I want to crop my `text` element, but not anything else — e.g. I want to leave the `0.9` in the *x*-axis alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set a clipbox for the text as [described in the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.scatter(np.random.random(10), np.random.random(10))
ax.text(0.8, 0.5, "a rather long string",
        clip_box=ax.clipbox, clip_on=True)
ax.set_xlim(0, 1)

plt.show()
```

This results in

[image]